# ManyToMany in Django admin: select none

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Having `A = ManyToManyField(B, null=True, blank=True)`, when I go in A's admin page, it seems I can't unselect every entries in the ManyToMany box after having clicked on a B element.
And even if I don't click on any entry, there is a related B element selected after saving (the first B element I guess).

But I want to add A elements without having to relate them to any one of B...

Is there any way to say to Django admin to select no element? (other than creating a dummy B element for those situations)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like a browser issue rather than a Django issue.

To unselect an element in a multiple select, press the **Ctrl** key (linux / windows) or the **Command** key (mac) when you click on it.

Comment: Ok got it :) I was thinking that when the B field was appearing in the box after saving was meaning that it's related!! (related = selection = highlighted in grey or something like that :) )

Comment: You might find the [`filter_horizonal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) and [`filter_vertical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical) model admin options helpful. They improve the user interface for many to many relationships in the Django admin.